# Error in merging two raster files (precipitation) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, precipitation

The newly computed geotiff shows the extent of both raster layers, but only the data of one. If I use identify features tool it gives me only the values of the visible part not of the other part. I use Float32. What am I doing wrong?